# How should I concatenate json response object with variable J of for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am getting a JSON response as below:

```
{
  "name" : "chanchal",
  "login3" : "1534165718",
  "login7" : "1534168971",
  "login6" : "1534168506",
  "login5" : "1534166215",
  "login9" : "1534170027",
  "login2" : "1534148039",
  "lastname" : "khandelwal",
  "login4" : "1534166200",
  "login10" : "1534147907",
  "login8" : "1534169966",
  "login1" : "1534147962",
  "id" : "1",
  "user_id" : "1002"
}
```

My Code for Script function is as below :

```
function showHistory(usrId)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: loc+"AdminController/loginHistory",
        data: { usrId : usrId },
        success : function(data)
        {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            var output="";
            console.log(data);
            output += '<div class="tabs">';
            output += '<ul class="tab-links"><li class="active"><a href="#name">'+obj.name+' '+obj.lastname+'</a></li></ul>';
            output += '<div class="tab-content">';
            output += '<table class="flat-table"><tbody><tr><th>No.</th><th>Login Time</th></tr>';              
            for(var j = 1 ; j<= 10 ; j++)
            {
                output += '<tr>';
                output += '<td>'+j+'</td>';
                output += '<td>'+obj.login+'</td>'; // ON THIS LINE I WANT TO CONCATENATE login with 1 then 2 then 3 till j loop continues
                output += '</tr>';  
            }

            output += '</tbody></table>';
            output += '</div></div>';
            $('#result_tbl').html(output);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to print the value of login time in a table. I here just want to concatenate login with 1 then 2 then 3 till login10. How should I do this?
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
output += '<td>'+obj.login+'</td>';
```

To:

```
output += '<td>'+obj['login'+j]+'</td>';
```

In order to access properties `login1`, `login2`... `login10`